# Issue with MSBuild after installing KB983583

Tags: msbuild

It seems that [KB983583](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983583) affects MSBuild. All my builds are hanging after installing this update on Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Here is a part of thread dump from TeamCity:

> Thread id=3708 priority=8 state=Wait reason=ExecutionDelay
>    at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetNativeSortKey(System.Int32 lcid, System.Int32 flags, System.String source, System.Int32 cchSrc, System.Byte sortKey)
>    at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetScriptTag(System.Int32 lcid, System.String script)
>    at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.CacheSyntheticNameLcidMapping()
>    at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.InitSyntheticMapping()
>    at System.Globalization.CultureTable.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes types)
>    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CultureStringUtilities.PopulateCultureInfoArray()
>    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CultureStringUtilities.IsValidCultureString(System.String cultureString)
>    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.FindSatellites(Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Reference reference)
>    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.FindAssociatedFiles()
>    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.ComputeClosure()
>   ...

After uninstalling KB983583 everything works.

Did anybody reproduce this issue?